# Birt in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, birt

I have a spring boot application and birt reporting is integrated with it.I am able to generate the birt report and everything working fine while I am testing from my IDE.Now I generated the spring boot jar and while starting the application from jar file it throws exception. The line throwing exception is

> birtReportEngine =
>   reportEngineFactory.createReportEngine(engineConfig);

Any pointers to fix this?.Thanks in advance

> Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Unable to construct
>   Calendar
>           at com.ibm.icu.util.CalendarServiceShim.createInstance(CalendarServiceShim.java:69)
>   ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.getInstanceInternal(Calendar.java:1628)
>   ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at com.ibm.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1590) ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:507)
>   ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:472)
>   ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at com.ibm.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat.(SimpleDateFormat.java:386)
>   ~[com.ibm.icu-4.4.2.v20110823.jar!/:na]
>           at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineLogger.generateUniqueLogFileName(EngineLogger.java:224)
>   ~[org.eclipse.birt.runtime-4.2.0.jar!/:na]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the dependency like below solved the issue

```
<!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.innoventsolutions.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.8.0-20180626</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```